# What actually handles exceptions in Tomcat + Spring?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I recently realized that I'm not entirely sure which exact exception handler prints error info to the logs. The reason for it was that at some point the stacktraces disappeared from the log when the error happens in controller, e.g.

```
    ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        ...
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

started looking like

```
    ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

(stacktrace is completely absent).
As far as I understand it isn't related to the logger settings as both messages still have level ERROR, so it must be something inside the handler which decides whether to print stacktrace or not. Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Comment: In your case the exception reached Tomcat's code and was logged by Tomcat. The exception was passed as parameter in the call to the logger, so your logger must have stacktrace logging disabled. Can you add the configuration of your logger?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks for the insight, I tried to find any settings in tomcat related to printing stacktraces but couldn't, can you suggest where to find them? regarding the configuration of the logger - I see only log path defined in the properties, maybe it's overridden somewhere in server config as running the app locally prints those stactraces fine, is there's a way to print all the related settings in runtime to compare those from local and server? (sry if I'm asking noob questions :) )

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the missing stack trace is a JVM optimisation. It's a bit hard to find documentation for, but you can read a little about it [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/release-notes-introduction.html) (search for OmitStackTraceInFastThrow).

To disable the optimisation use `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`.